# Jquery Mobile form action with perl returns blank page, php works fine though

Tags: jquery, perl, mobile

I have a simple jquery mobile html with form/action in it, but the perl just returns blank page, suppose to print "Hello World". But if I use php, it prints just fine.

Is Jquery Mobile and perl not compatible with each other?

This is the main html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
       href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script 
      src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <!--THIS WORKS FINE<form method="post" action="joo1.php">
      -->
      <form method="post" action="cgi-bin/joo1.pl"><!-- THIS RETURNS BLANK -->
        <div>
          <h3>Login information</h3>
            <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Username">
            <label for="pswd" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="passw" id="pswd" placeholder="Password">
            <label for="log">Keep me logged in</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="login" id="log" value="1" data-mini="true">
            <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Log in">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h1>Footer Text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
and the joo1.pl looks like this (returns blank page):

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "Hello, World!";
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
and the joo1.php looks like this (works fine):

```php
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    echo "Hello, World!";
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: What's in your error log?

Comment: How's do I see the error log?

Comment: How would I know? It's not my server.

Comment: "Is Jquery Mobile and perl not compatible with each other?" — The client has no idea what programming language was used to produce the HTTP response, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: If I remove the Jquery mobile includes, everything's fine, these are the includes:<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: once I inserted them back in, perl returns blank

Comment: @ArgonneFarm Please take the time to share your solution in an answer if you found what the source of your difficulties were.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what is going on here. Check your text file line ending characters on the Perl script. If you moved the code from a Windows box to a *NIX server the Perl interpreter may be seeing your code as being all on one line - specifically the bang line. When this happens you will get no output and no error in the Apache log files.